# How can I use CSS to create knockout (transparent) text with this HTML layout?

Tags: html, css, text, transparent, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a layout in which some letters are transparent with a white background behind them, but the transparency shows all the way through to a gradient background several levels up the HTML hierarchy. Basically, I'm trying to achieve something like the following:

[image]

Here's my current HTML and CSS:

```css
.header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #2121CC, #1E0674);
}

.header>div {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.header>div>h1 {
  display: flex;
}

.header>div>h1>span {
  background: #FFF;
  color: transparent;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
    <h1>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was referencing the following CSS Tricks article on how to do this:

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/

But the issue in my case seems to be that I want the text to be transparent and show through the white background all the way to the `.header` element three levels up the HTML hierarchy.

Is this possible with just CSS, and if so, how? I've tried everything I can think of to no avail. Thank you.

---

**Edit**: It's worth mentioning that the CSS Tricks article uses the `-webkit-background-clip: text;` property, but when I add that to my CSS, it doesn't change anything and it's crossed out when you inspect the corresponding elements in the browser. In other words, I don't think it's supported and actually does anything anymore (I could be wrong).

Comment: Looks like you're missing a key property from that article: [`-webkit-background-clip-text`](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/#webkit-background-clip-text)

Comment: Good point. I added an edit to my original post to point out why I purposefully removed it. Thank you.

Comment: which browser are you testing in? `-webkit-background-clip: text` will only work in webkit browsers (chrome, safari, new edge). firefox (but not chrome and safari) supports the un-prefixed version (`background-clip: text`) so you'll want to add both.

Comment: Woodrow, thanks for noting the need to add the non-prefixed version. You're absolutely right. Unfortunately, that did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) :

```css
.header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, red,#2121CC, #1E0674, yellow);
}

.header>div {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100rem;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.header>div>h1 {
  display: flex;
}

.header>div>h1>span {
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  mix-blend-mode:screen
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div>
    <h1>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
      <span>A</span>
      <span>B</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This totally worked! Thanks, G-Cyrillus. I've never even heard of this `mix-blend-mode` property before, but it seems pretty handy. Thank you!